# Reserving space in html markup or adsense ads

Tags: html, css, adsense

I'm in the process of building a website (many things are still not functioning), but I'm now adressing look and feel. I would like to have space reserved for ads in my php templates. Is it enough to just add a `<div class='advertisement'>` and use standard CSS to hold the position?
I know this will work for my purposes, howver I am woundering if once Google crawls my site in future will require less work to have ads displaying.
p.s. I have also readthrough Google's guidlines on where ads should be placed and hava a differnet look then rest of page Just woundering if I'm missing something.

Comment: You can reserve the space for the ads, but till you do not have ads to place you can simply comment your markup, and when you place those ads, you can remove out the comments

Comment: okay, but there's no way to push in sample ads, or anything like that in the meantime? Just to have look user will

Comment: What is the problem? `<div ...></div>` with CSS that sets dimensions is sufficient for reserving space, and Google sees it as empty (as it is) and ignores it, until you put some content there. This seems to simple that the question arises whether the problem is something beyond this simple (or trivial) thing and what that might be.

Comment: Thge question is very simple like stated ... I was woundering if there is something better you can do. But not the less if either of you want to add your  comments as a answer ill accept it if not ill delete the question in next 20 or so minutes

Comment: @brendanmorrison Keep sample banners with a text **Advertise Here**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `<div class='advertisement'></div>` (with no content between the tags) and set the dimensions of the element in CSS, this is sufficient for reserving space, and Google sees it as empty (as it is) and ignores it, until you put some content there. There is no way, and no need, to inform Google about the future content of the page.

If you wish to insert some dummy content into the element, like “Advertize here” (which is really an ad of a kind) or “Reserved for ads”, that’s OK. It may help you during development and evaluation. Whether they are OK for real pages when launched needs to be considered carefully. But to search engines, that would be just content, and probably not relevant – it does not no much harm, but neither does it help. (We don’t expect people to search for such things, do we?)